# Deactivate likes from people I follow in Twitter

Tags: twitter

I have a question about the likes in Twitter.  In my home page I can see the tweets from everyone I follow, but sometimes a tweet from someone I do not follow appears, because someone liked it. Is there any configuration I can do to make this stop?  I have already tried almost everything from the settings menu, but nothing seems to work.  Can someone help me?